# PHPUnit - Running all tests twice with cache on/off?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'd like to make sure my code always works as intended whether a memcached server is available or not.

Most of my functions look like this:

```
function foo($parameter,$force = FALSE)
{
    $result = Cache::get('foo_'.$parameter);

    if (empty($result) || $force)
    {
        // Do stuff with the DB...
        $result = "something";
        Cache::put('foo_'.$parameter,$result,$timeout);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Now in a TestCase I'm doing this:

```
class MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    function testFoo()
    {
        $result = $myClass->foo($parameter);
        $this->assertSomething($result);
    }
}
```

I can disable caches globally during PHPUnit's `setUp()` like this:

```
class MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    protected function setUp()
    {
        Cache::disable();
    }
}
```

After calling `Cache::disable()`, all calls to `Cache::get()` will return `false` during that request. Now, I want to run all tests in this class twice, once with `Cache::disable();` and once without.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is to create a `MyClassNoCacheTest` that extends from `MyClassTest` and just overwrite (or implement) the `setUp` method in `MyClassNoCacheTest`

Comment: So, in `MyClassNoCacheTest` how would I go about calling every single test method from `MyClassTest`?

Comment: It will be taken care of by `phpunit`, for all intents and purposes when `MyClassNoCacheTest` extends `MyClassTest` it inherits all its methods (tests) too, so they will run again, just like if you copied them manually to a different file and just added the `setUp` method